# Kotlin n=10 and must include loops

Tags: kotlin

I need to use loops and arithmetic expressions to code n=10

The correct output of the program:

1

2

6

24

120

720

5040

40320

362880

3628800

Please guide me through this!

Comment: Hi Eric! Welcome to Stackoverflow! What did you try already? Where did you get stuck? Do you have any code to share?

Comment: I do need to use factorial but need steps of how to code it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you need factorial:

```
val num = 10
var factorial: Long = 1
for (i in 1..num) {
    factorial *= i.toLong()
    println("$factorial")
}
```

Comment: Yes, the goal is to write a program pronting factorials for numbers from 1 to n and it should produce a list of correct numbers, the numbers in the post.

Comment: @Eric so you can use this code and change `num` value to what you like. It will printing factorial value. You can check this code output in [kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/coipBoF1L).

Comment: Cany you explain the process in detail? Im being mentored by a russian software engineer and he lists a couple examples but he fails to go into detail. He says im overyhinking it and i should be like a kid and just apply information rather then just solely understanding it.

Comment: @Eric it's just a fundamental things. What exactly you didn't get? How loop working or what?